# InputFunctionException, KeyError in Snakemake

Tags: python-3.x, bioinformatics, snakemake

I am trying to run snakemake rule shown below but I am getting *InputFunctionException* and *KeyError*. What could be causing such an error to occur while using lambda wildcards? Is there a way you can print the variable normal_bam on the terminal?

```
rule tumor_with_matched_normal:
          normal_bam = lambda wildcards: os.path.join(
                        "/home/bio/processed_bams/" + config[wildcards.sample]["normal"] + "." + config["ref_basename"] + ".sorted.bam")
```

Comment: What is the content of `config`? And what is the key that can't be found?

Comment: Thanks. The config file is as follows:                                                                           
{"all_samples": ["_CK1_R1_blood_01", "_CK2_R1_cancer_01"], "R1": {"normal": "_CK1_R1_blood_01", "tumor": "_CK2_R1_cancer_01"}, "ref_basename": "hg19"}

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The error was from the config file, where I did not define the sample dictionary which contains "R1" and "R2". Thanks KeyboadCat for the point. Much appreciated.